# Constexpr doesn't get evaluated when computed using const variable outside function

Tags: c++, constexpr

I present two code snippets, one of them compiles and the other doesn't.

The one that doesn't compile:

```
class Solution {
    public:
    const int MAX_NUM = 100;
    const int MAX_SIZE = 200;
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
        bitset<(MAX_NUM*MAX_SIZE)/2 + 1> bits(1);
        
        int sum = 0;
        for(int num: nums)
        {
            sum += num;
            bits |= bits << num;
        }
        return !(sum % 2) and bits[sum/2];
    }
};
```

Gives the errors:

`error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression`

`implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function`

One that does:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool canPartition(vector<int>& nums) {
        const int MAX_NUM = 100;
        const int MAX_SIZE = 200;
        bitset<(MAX_NUM*MAX_SIZE)/2 + 1> bits(1);
        
        int sum = 0;
        for(int num: nums)
        {
            sum += num;
            bits |= bits << num;
        }
        return !(sum % 2) and bits[sum/2];
    }
};
```

I read `constexpr` documentation and found two things which might be issue here:

> constexpr must immediately initialized.

> It must have constant destruction, i.e. it is not of class type

Could you point out what's the issue here and help me understand the problem?

Comment: implicit use of 'this' pointer is only allowed within the evaluation of a call to a 'constexpr' member function. This kind of says it all, in your first version MAX_NUM and MAX_SIZE are members of the class. And would implictly use the "this" pointer. In the second version you use local variables (constants) and this is fine for evaluating the bitset size (no "this" pointer required)

Comment: Did you intend to allow `MAX_NUM` and `MAX_SIZE` to vary from object to object? Since they are `const`, they cannot be changed after construction, but (since they are not `static`) a constructor would be allowed to initialize those fields to other values on an object-by-object basis (hence the need to access them via `this` within a member function, but that's a tidbit more for the answer than for this request for clarification).

Comment: I understand. Thanks @PKramer

Comment: Hello @JaMiT. No I did not intend to change them. I declared them as static and it worked! I get the error now. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since Templates are evaluated at compile time, their arguments cannot be anything that the compiler can't "predict". In your first code the member variables `MAX_NUM` and `MAX_SIZE` are `const` values, meaning they cannot be changed after an instance of the class `Solution` is made and they are initialized. But *for each instance of* `Solution` *they can still be initialized with different, unpredictable values in a constructor.* The default value that you set them equal to (respectively 100 and 200) are only used if they aren't initialized during creation of an instance. Take a look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class A
{
private:
    const int m_foo = 1;
public:
    A() {}
    A(int num) : m_foo(num) {}
    int foo() { return m_foo; }
};

int main()
{
    A a1;         //a1.m_foo initialized with default value
    cout << "Enter desired m_foo for a2: ";
    int foo;
    cin >> foo;
    A a2(foo);    //a2.m_foo initialized with user input
    cout << "m_foo for a1: " << a1.foo() << endl 
        << "m_foo for a2: " << a2.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the `const` member variable called `m_foo` can be any value entered by the user.

However, *when defining a `const` variable inside the scope of a function, that value cannot be changed and is therefore qualified as a template argument*, i.e. it is similar to a `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3):

The error messages explain what's going on quite well. The template argument to the declaration of `bits` needs to be a constant expression. However, if you use non-static members like `MAX_NUM` inside a non-constexpr member function, you end up evaluating the `this` pointer, which is not allowed. [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression):

> A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would not evaluate any one of the following:
>
> > 1. the `this` pointer, except in a constexpr function that is being evaluated as part of the expression

When the variables like `MAX_NUM` are declared inside the member function, they're not members of the class, and so they can be used as constant expressions, which is why the first version compiles.

Comment: So, seems like the solution is to mark `MAX_NUM` and `MAX_SIZE` as `static`, so that they do not depend on the `this` pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, that's one solution. Though if those variables are not being used anywhere else, they could be declared inside the member function as well.